# What's the analogy of a single photon from the perspective of "classical electromagnetic wave"?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

I guess there isn't an accurate analogy. But what is the best analogy we can use?

It seems an idea sinusoidal wave of a single frequency doesn't fit as a photon at all.

In a certain sense, at least for the scenario of a photon traveling in a medium, can we imagine it as a wave packet (e.g. like a single packet in an amplitude modulated wave shown in the figure below)?

(Just for the purpose to illustrate E in x axis, ignoring B.)

[image]

What does the frequency of a photon correspond to in an electromagnetic wave?
Does the speed of a photon resemble the speed of the wave packet (i.e. group velocity)?

[UPDATE]

If there is no analogy for photons, instead can we imagine a pulse of light as a wave packet?

Comment: There is no such analogy. Photons don't travel, for one thing. They can be created and they can be detected/destroyed, but one can't make any sense of classical pictures for their "movement". A classical electromagnetic wave can be characterized by a quantum field that has a large photon number, but a photon can not be characterized by a classical electromagnetic wave.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess there is indeed no analogy at all that we can use to assist imagining a photon in EM field. Shame.

Comment: I would say the deeper insight is, indeed, that there is no classical analogy for what happens at the quantum level. Many people have tried to come up with such analogies, but they all fail on one level or another. The closest you can get, if you want to go there, is the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics. Feynman wrote a fine little book about it that layman and physicists can enjoy equally: "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter". In there you find the closest classical analogy to quantum mechanics that is technically correct, in my opinion.